# Python Pandas EMWA module not working?

Tags: python, pandas, module

I am trying to run this script:

https://github.com/sshashank124/crypto-rsi-tracker/blob/master/rsi-tracker.py

and I am getting the error regarding Panda EWMA. How do I fix this?

```
ups_avg = pd.ewma(ups, span=RSI_N)[-1]
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewma'
```

I already have CONFIG.YML file configured properly

Comment: Looks like `ewma` was deprecated in favor of `ewm`

Comment: @chrisz i tried with ewm and it still gives me same error